# Cannot Extend partition with GParted

Tags: partition, gparted

I am trying to extend my ext4 partition using the GParted application. I've tried a number of times to get this to work, but it seems impossible.

[image: My GParted setup]

I've seen many threads about the issue being the unallocated space isn't next to the correct partition, there's a swap in the way, etc.  But this isn't my case, as the unallocated space is directly to the left of the ext4 partition I want to extend.
When I go to resize, it doesn't give me the option to move to the left, just the right:

[image: No left slider]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the partition mounted? Your screenshot suggests it is.

Comment: Yes it is, should this not be the case?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify your mounted root partition with gparted which doesn't work. You have to boot gparted from a [live CD/USB](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) from USB or CD, or boot from another linux (live system) since you cannot unmount this partition while being in use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will try this!

Comment: In a little more detail, you can resize a mounted partition, but you can’t move it.